# scrollView doesn't adjust horizontally

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Basically, I need a scrollView which is shrinked horizontally. Now, when I insert a bunch of text in it, it doesn't adjust it, text just goes over the edge of the scrollView, like this: http://prntscr.com/ai0100

This is my scrollView code:

```
local scrollView = widget.newScrollView
    {
        hideBackground = false,
        hideScrollBar = true,
        left = 64,
        top = 0,
        width = contW - 128,
        height = contH,
        topPadding = 256,
        bottomPadding = 20,
        horizontalScrollDisabled = true,
        verticalScrollDisabled = false,
    }
```

I insert a bunch of text later, and screenshot above is the result. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Read this: https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/newText.html

In order to wrap a text you have to set the display.newText() width parameter accordingly.

So something like

```
scrollView.newText
{
  text = "I am a super text"  
  width = 123 -- replace with your desired width

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another way:

```
local lotsOfTextObject = display.newText( lotsOfText, display.contentCenterX-40, 0, samewidthasscrollview, 0, native.systemFont, 30)

scrollView:insert( lotsOfTextObject )
```